# Website zoomed out on Android default browser

Tags: android, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

I'm kind of lost here. Due to a deadline I didn't have the chance to properly test the website on every device and now people are telling me it's not showing up properly on the default Android browser. The user shouldn't be able to zoom out of the bounds of the `<body>`.

Trying to change the viewport tag doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for responsive features. The website is shown as follows:

[Screenshot (used BrowserStack)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNmLt.png)

[This is the website in question.](http://owow.io)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you give this tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">  in head?

Comment: This is my viewport tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Oh i see. Can you try the above one also and let me know?

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you tried this? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: Yes I tried that aswell.

Comment: Oh i see For android try this <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
body{
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

inside your css file, which will make the width of the body tag 100% of the display size.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to help, either.

Comment: Try using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> inside your head tag.